# How to display parsed JSON data in UI?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, codable

I have parsed data from a JSON object that I received from an API call. As of now, I can print the JSON data in the debugger console, however I am trying to convert the parsed JSON back into data that can be displayed in the UI. I have two models, and an example of a JSON object looks as such:

```
{ 
  "query": "milk",
  "sort": "relevance",
  "responseGroup": "base",
  "totalResults": 693,
  "start": 1,
  "numItems": 10,
  "items": [{
    "itemId": 10291863,
    "parentItemId": 10291863,
    "name": "Carnation Vitamin D Added Evaporated Milk, 12 oz",
    "msrp": 1.79,
    "salePrice": 1.48
  }]
}
```

I only want to display information that details the `name` and `salePrice` keys. However since the JSON is nested I don't know how to reach to that layer in order to retrieve the values. Here is my data model code:

```
struct Item: Codable {
  let query: String
  let sort: String
  let responseGroup: String
  let totalResults: Int
  let start: Int
  let numItems = 25
  let items: [Product]
}

struct Product: Codable {
  let name: String
  let salePrice: Double
}
```

Code to my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var itemField: UITextField!  
  @IBAction func filterButton(_ sender: Any) {
    var components = URLComponents()
    components.scheme = "http"
    components.host = "api.walmartlabs.com"
    components.path = "/v1/search"
    let queryItemKey = URLQueryItem(name: "apiKey", value: secretKey)
    var queryItemQuery = URLQueryItem(name: "query", value: itemField.text)
    components.queryItems = [queryItemKey, queryItemQuery]
    let searchURL = components.url       
    //Task to make API Network Call
    guard let url = components.url else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
      if error != nil {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
      }  
      guard let data = data else { return }
      //Implement JSON decoding and parsing
      do {
        //Decode retrived data with JSONDecoder and assing type of Item object
        let productData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data)
            print(productData) 
      } catch let jsonError {
        print(jsonError)
      }          
    }.resume()
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
}
```

The print log shows the following when I run my code (again, I only want to show the `name` and `salePrice` values. Is there a way I can place these values in an array or convert these values in a way I can populate my UI with? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are already parsing that value in Array with `[Product]` so what you want to do?

Comment: I want to take all the values from the keys `name` and `salePrice`and place them in their own respective arrays.

Comment: You can map your fields this way (I've updated my answer) : `let names = productData.items.map { $0.name }` and `let salePrices = productData.items.map { $0.salePrice }`

Comment: **Do not** put the values in separate arrays if you got already a custom struct. Never do that.

Comment: Can you explain why? @vadian

Comment: 1) You got already the data object. 2) The properties which belong to one product are always in sync. 3) You have to maintain multiple arrays. For example you have to ensure that the length of the arrays match otherwise the app will crash 4) It's much more efficient to get the object by index **once** and access the properties than getting all properties by index from different arrays

Comment: Could you give a simple example in code?

Comment: An example of what? `Product` is a perfect data object. See my answer how to populate the table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a data source array

```
var products = [Product]()
```

After parsing the data assign the products array to the data source array and reload the table view

```
...
let productData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data)
self.products = productData.items
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In `numberOfRowsInSection` return `products.count`

In `cellForRow` get the current product and assign the values to labels

```
let product = products[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = product.name
cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "\(product.salePrice)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple loop:

```
for product in productData.items {
    print("\(product.name) : \(product.salePrice)")
}
```

or in a closure way:

```
productData.items.forEach { print("\($0.name) : \($0.salePrice)") }
```

In fact your products are already in an array: `productData.items`

**EDIT after comments**

You can map your fields to get each values in separate arrays:

```
let names = productData.items.map { $0.name } 
let salePrices = productData.items.map { $0.salePrice }
```